# PHP turn array of objects into key/value array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of php objects that looks like

```
array(3) {
  [0] object(stdClass)#153 (2) {
    ["key"] "a"
    ["val"] "2"
  }
  [1] object(stdClass)#154 (2) {
    ["key"] "b"
    ["val"] "2"
  }
  [2] object(stdClass)#155 (2) {
    ["key"] "c"
    ["val"] "5"
  }
}
```

and I want to turn it into this

```
array(3) {
  ["a"] 2
  ["b"] 2
  ["c"] 5
}
```

I've tried some variations of foreach loops but can't quite figure it out because of each value of the original array being an object with two keys. How can I clean this up and get it into a straight array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$newArray=array();
foreach($yourObjects as $obj)
{
 $newArray[$obj->key]=$obj->val;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

Comment: The first line is not neccessary.

Comment: It is necessary for any good code. That `$newArray` might be a duplicate name of something up in the code, it can lead to unexpected behavior, it can make it difficult to understand, so on and so forth. It is one of the bad things with PHP that it allows programmers to work with variables without even declaring them first.

Comment: It's not necessary, but _very welcome_ : initializing your variables is a good habit. It may save a lot of debugging time. Btw: OP wants _associative array_

Comment: There are a lot of things that are not necessary, but important. Indentation is one example, its not necessary but any code without it makes life tough.

Comment: Fixed for associative array

Answer (score 1):

Just Try.

```
$array=array();
foreach($obj as $objVal)
{
 $array[$objVal->key]=$objVal->val;
}
    echo "<pre>";
     print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

in `for loop`

```
$arrayvalues=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($yourobject);$i++)
{
 $arrayvalues[]=$yourobject[$i]->val;
}

print_r($arrayvalues);
```